# Passing data from template to component

Tags: vue.js

I have the following, which for my understanding should pass the value of html attribute to the @Prop with the same name however my console.log is always undefined. How is this accomplished?

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({})
    export default class RelayComponent extends Vue {
    @Prop([String]) service: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(this.service);
...
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <div service="expecting this value passed"></div>
</template>
<script src="./relay.ts"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Vue props

Vue props are intended to pass data from a parent vue component or instance to a child vue component.

So you have a vue component, you set up a `@Prop` and then you get the prop for the **html of the parent**. Should you have a `my-parent` and `my-child` components, the `my-parent` template could be:

```
<template>
    <my-child count="7"></my-child>
</template>
```

So a child component like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="counter">{{count}}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from 'vue';
  import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

  @Component({})
    export default class myChild extends Vue {
    @Prop() count: number;
  }
</script>
```

Would get `7` as its count prop.

Now, in your case, there is only one component, and you're trying to setup the `service` variable of the component **from** the HTML. This is sort of weird because the point of Vue is to achieve **declarative rendering** from the component data: is the HTML who reacts to data changes, not your component who gets data from the HTML.

(Of course, you can also setup `v-model` and event listeners to make your components react to user input, but that's another story).

Basically, if I understood correctly what you want to do, your issue is that you're trying to get the `service` prop from the HTML of the very RelayComponent component.

Instead, you should setup the `service` prop **in the component parent**:

```
// Code of some parent component that renders the RelayComponent
<template>
  <relay-component service="this would set the service prop as a string"></relay-component>
</template>
```

Only, when dealing with objects, you usually don't pass down a plain string, but a javascript object, and a `service` variable probably is an object, so changes are you're behind something like this:

```
<template>
  <relay-component v-bind:service="serviceVariableInTheParentComponent"></relay-component>
</template>
```

Where the parent component has a `service` variable in its `data`.

### Constructor and lifehooks

Be wary about explicitly calling `constructor` in vue class components. If you modify the component state in the constructor, you can break the component.

Probably, you should consider to ever use the `created()` [lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) instead of `constructor()` in every Vue component.